# Disable product add to cart button if quantity of that product exceeds 10 on cart

Tags: php, opencart

I've been trying to find solution for my problem, but have failed so far.

I have a request to disable Add to cart button if customer adds more than 10 items per product to cart.

The code for my button is as follows:

```
              <?php if($logged) {  ?><button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button><?php } ?>
```

I am using opencart v 2.2.0. Is there a way to define limit in the Add to cart button code? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated, as I am totally lost on this one. I am sure the solution is there, but I can't seem to see it myself. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This is quite possible.. :)

Comment: @AliZia Can you tell me how to do it, please? Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you need to check individual product to check whether the product
>   is qty is 10 on cat or not. as below code
>
> controller/product.php

```
$cart_product_detail=$this->cart->getProducts();
           //print_r($cart_product_detail);
           $data['cart_product_info']=array();
           foreach($cart_product_detail as $cart_info){
                //print_r($cart_info);
                $data['cart_product_info'][] = array(
                    'cart_product_id'  => $cart_info['product_id'],
                    'cart_product_qty' => $cart_info['quantity']
                );
```

> on product.tpl

```
<?php //print_r($cart_product_info);
                    $current_product=$product_id;
                    $cart_quantity=0;
                    foreach($cart_product_info as $cart_prod):
                        if($current_product==$cart_prod['cart_product_id']){
                          $cart_quantity=$cart_prod['cart_product_qty'];
                        }else{
                        $cart_quantity=0;
                        }
                    endforeach;
                    //$product_qty=$product_qty-$cart_quantity;
              ?>
               <?php if($cart_quantity<10):?>
                <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
              <?php endif;?>
```

> if you need to check total quantity of car no mather the which
>   prodcuct then

```
product.php
    $data['total_product_cart']=$this->cart->countProducts();

product.tpl
 <?php if($total_product_cart>10):?>
                    <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
<?php else:?>
<button type="button" ><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
                  <?php endif;?>
```

> or you can use in any page where you like to disable the add to cart button.
>   once you get the total product in cart you can disable add to cart button in various way
>
> yous on product.php and where you need then you will get total product
>   and make the decision

Comment: Hi,
@Samir Karmacharya  Thank you very much for your suggestion. I managed to put code to product.php, but when I put code for product.tpl I get error:

"Notice: Undefined variable: product_qty in".  Any suggestions, please? Thank you.

Comment: you need to replace comment out the line $product_qty=$product_qty-$cart_quantity;

Comment: Thanx, I just did that, but the problem is my Add to cart button is now gone even though I haven't added any product to my cart. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I just need it to be disabled for every product if there are more than 10 products in cart. Thank you.

Comment: first code for the individual code, if you need to count the cart total quantity using second code "$data['total_product_cart']=$this->cart->countProducts();" and if that total_product_cart is more than 10 you can use if and else condition

Comment: i have added few code which make you more clear. please have a look

Comment: Hi Samir,

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, but the code isn't working. It keeps hiding my button eventhough my cart is empty. I am using the code:

$data['total_product_cart']=$this->cart->countProducts(); for product.php

and for product.tpl I put what you wrote (if else code).

Comment: you can check what value is coming then make you decision. it will give $total_product_car 0 when cart is empty and else it give according to cart quantity

Comment: I am doing everything you asked me to, but still the code doesn't seem to be working.  There were some syntax errors, I fixed them, but still nothing....Do you have any idea why? I am grateful for your help.

Comment: when you print the total cart $data['total_product_cart']=$this->cart->countProducts();
work right? then this value compare in .tpl file and make a condition only. nothing to do more you need to use only if condition. still confuse and me on gmail. samirkarmacharya68@

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already know how to count the items in your cart?
if so make a javascript statement like this

```
    if(cartcount > 10)
    {
      document.getElementById("button-cart").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("button-cart").disabled = false;
    }
```